# C++ Win async sockets. Is it possible to interrupt select()

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, events

I have a listening thread that waiting for reading on few socket using select and FD_SET. The story is. At some point I will add another socket to the pool and need to abort select and re-initialize FD_SET array fo select. I have an Event to signal pool changes. But how select can react to my Event?
select() at this point of time use timeval with waiting interval of 20 sec and I don't want to changed time to lower value. I don't want frequently re-start select() by timeout...

Is there any way to abort select? What would be the right approach to inform/restart select and force using of new list of socket(at least one socket will be added to pool)

And another question - Msdn says "The select function determines the status of one or more sockets, waiting if necessary, to perform synchronous I/O."
Does that mean that select is not designed to work with sockets that turned to use using async operation?

Comment: how are you making the socket async? Which api?

Comment: @johnathon: sockets support asynchronous (overlapped) I/O by default on Windows, unless you disable it using the `WSASocket()` call.

Comment: @AndréCaron care to point me to some documentation that backs that up? As i am under the impression(as well as my reference is from bob quinn and dave shute) that all sockets created are blocking .. unless you later (after creation) specify otherwise.

Comment: @johnathon: you're mixing up blocking/non-blocking and asynchronous I/O.  From the documentation on [`WSASelect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742212.aspx): "By default, a socket created with the `WSASocket()` function will not have this overlapped attribute set.  In contrast, the `socket()` function creates a socket that supports overlapped I/O operations as the default behavior."

Comment: Socket created by default as blocking. I use ioctlsocket to set them into async mode.

Comment: When a socket is created, it operates in blocking mode by default (nonblocking mode is disabled). This is consistent with BSD sockets.

Comment: @Damir: "Non-blocking" is not synonymous with "asynchronous".  `recv()` is still synchronous for a non-blocking socket.  The thing is that it will return immediately if no data is available.

Comment: @AndréCaron i suggest you read the question again, my friend, because he is stating he's using async sockets with select .. now unless he's using WSAAsyncSelect() , which i doubt highly, he's not using async sockets, he's using blocking, and ASIO is thread pooling with blocking sockets ( basically). i can actually link a nice article by ken kerr that'll delve into the deep about the subject if you like

Comment: @johnathon: I know and fully understand what is in the question.  *You* mentioned "making the socket async".  Using `select()` and `read()` involves *absolutely no asynchronous I/O*.  The `select()`-based Boost ASIO provides asynchronous *completion notifications* by implementing a proactor-style API on top of a reactor framework, in contrast with the Windows I/O completion port-based implementation which actually performs asynchronous I/O and really implements a reactor framework.

Comment: @Damir, I'll dig into the references i have and see if i can find you an answer , however off the top of my head the way to cancel a select (i think ) is to call select again with no flag indicators, the WSAAsyncSelect() follows this usage model.

Comment: @AndréCaron i qoute "Does that mean that select is not designed to work with sockets that turned to use using async operation?"

Comment: @johnathon: To which I responded "sockets are enabled for asynchronous I/O by default on Windows unless you *disable it while creating the socket*".  You cannot "turn" it later.

Comment: I think WSAAsyncSelect requires one socket handle only and hWND. It's not what I need. I need to wait on few sockets, which previously was turned into non-blocking mode. That's all what I have now by design (I can change it if get another proper advise) Previously I had a thread per socket and had no issues to call WSAEventSelect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `WSAEventSelect()` and `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` instead of `select()`. That way, your pool can create a separate event with `WSACreateEvent()` and signal it with `WSASetEvent()` to wake up `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` when needed.

Comment: Thas's rigth. +1. Need just to add array of events (each per socket) and the puzzle is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want select() to wake up, the easiest way is to send a byte to one of the sockets that select() is waiting on for read access.  One way to implement that without affecting functionality of the existing sockets is to create a pair of sockets specifically for that purpose and connect() one to the other.

Comment: Note to the implementer: since there is no [`socketpair()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/socketpair.html) on Windows, this actually requires quit a bit of work, as well as using an extra port for the extra "control" socket.

Comment: I had that idea to have extra socket to wake up select. I just don't beleve that is only the way to do that.